# How can you convert apostrophe type in PHP? Wrong one being echoed

Tags: php, wordpress, encoding, apostrophe

Basically I've got an array in PHP I'm looping through and outputting to an HTML text area. The data going in contains a list of strings, some of which use apostrophe's. EG: "Item One's Data", "Item Two Data", "Item Three's Data"....etc. The apostrophe being used are correct going in. But when they get outputted into the text area they change from the correct ' type to the incorrect ’ type. (they look VERY similar here but they are different characters).

I've tried using a variety of different things to swap these out such as str_replace, preg_replace, htmlspecialchars and mb_convert_encoding. None of which work. Either they are unable to find the ’ or even after it's replaced with a ' it still comes out as ’

My closest guess is an encoding issue. Because even after using mb_convert_encoding, when I check the result with mb_detect_encoding it still shows as ASCII type.

The html page does have this at the top:
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

Any insight for how I can force the use of the correct apostrophe format/encoding would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [tour], [ask], and [mcve].  As written the question is incomplete, it doesn't give us enough information.  It could be in your PHP, your database (if pulling the strings from one), or the HTML.  For the HTML page you might also be setting a font that does not display the characters you need.

Comment: Are we talking about this? https://www.webnots.com/4-ways-to-disable-smart-or-curly-quotes-in-wordpress/  Is this a Wordpress application?

Comment: @mickmackusa yes it appears that this is a Wordpress problem. I didn't realize it took the liberty of changing those characters. After some testing this appears to be the direction to find a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION** Turns out this appears to be a problem with Wordpress Smart or Curly Quotes changing the characters.

Was able to solve the issue by adding this to the theme functions file and/or in the plugin file.

`add_filter( 'run_wptexturize', '__return_false' );`